# how to get the distance or radian between two point on the earth with lng and lat?

Tags: geolocation, geometry, geospatial

how to get the distance or radian between two point on the earth with lng and lat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/third_party/s2/s2latlng.cc#L37

GetDistance() return a S1Angle, S1Angle::radians() will return the radians.

This belong to s2-geometry-library([google code](https://code.google.com/p/s2-geometry-library/) will close,i export it to my [github](https://github.com/himcc/s2-geometry-library). [Java](https://github.com/himcc/s2-geometry-library-java)).

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't want `mapReduce` in this case but actually the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/). Apart from the general first stage query you can run via [**`$geoNear`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) which is more efficient in your purpose.

```js
db.places.aggregate([
    { "$geoNear": {
        "near": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [ -88 , 30 ]
        },
        "distanceField": "dist"
    }},
    { "$match": {
        "loc": {
            "$centerSphere": [ [ -88 , 30 ] , 0.1 ]
        }
    }}
])
```

Or frankly, because the initial `$geoNear` stage will "project" an additional field into the document containing the "distance" from the queried "point of origin", then you can just "filter" on that element in a subsequent stage:

```js
db.places.aggregate([
    { "$geoNear": {
        "near": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [ -88 , 30 ]
        },
        "distanceField": "dist"
    }},
    { "$match": {
        "dist": { "$lte": 0.1 }
    }}
])
```

Since this is one option that can "produce/project" a value representing the distance in the result then that satisfies your first criteria. The "chaining" nature of the "aggregation framework" allows "additional filtering" or any other operation you need to perform after the filtering of the initial query.

So `$geoWithin` works just as well in the aggregation framework under a `$match` stage as it would in any standard query since it is not "dependant" on an "index" of geospatial origin to be present. It performs better in an initial query with one, but it does not need it.

Since your requirement is the "distance" from the point of origin, then the most logical thing to do is to perform an operation that will return such information. Such as this does.

Would love to include all of the relevant links in this response, but as a new responder then two links is all I am allowed for now.

---

One more relevant note:

The measurement of "distance" or "radius" in any operation is dependant on how your data is stored. If it is in a "legacy" or "key/pair or plain array" format then the value will be expressed in "radians", otherwise where the data is expressed in GeoJSON format on the "location" then the "distance data" is expressed in "meters" instead.

That is an important consideration given the libraries implemented by the MongoDB service and how this interacts with the data as you have it stored. There is of course documentation on this in the official resources should you care to look at that properly. And again, I cannot add those links at this time, unless this response sees some much needed love.

Comment: I really need a mapreduce job , instead of  aggregation framework.                 Maybe  the title should be "how to get the distance between two point on the earth with lng and lat?"               mongodb has  solved this problem.  So, i want to know how it solved this problem.

Comment: @cola The problem here is that only the `$geoNear` operation as mentioned and another separate command form of geoNear are the only way to return the projected "distance" between the point, and there is no way to invoke that with mapReduce. I could note that you really don't ask anything other than "how to return the distance", which the example of course does. You would be required to include the necessary JavaScript code in order to calculate a distance otherwise. It is likely that aggregation will be a better approach to the results you want anyway. It's certainly faster.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help！   But，i really need "how to get the distance or radian between two point on the earth with lng and lat?" .   My cluster is  a   hadoop cluster instead of mongodb.   My task is offline and batch process .   So ,i am sure that i don't need mongodb.  I have tried to find "how to get the distance or radian between two point on the earth with lng and lat?" in mongodb source ,but not find.  So ,i need help .